# unable to developer-unlock htc radar

Tags: unlocking

I can't unlock my htc radar, the error message I was getting is:

> unable to communicate to the phone. Please check that the phone is connected
>   with a USB cable and launch the zune software.

I have done both of these, but I still can't unlock it. Do you have any suggestions to resolve this problem?

Comment: This is a developer question, right? Developer questions are off topic here. You should try on  http://stackoverflow.com/ with the windows-phone-7 tag

Comment: @KateGregory Unlocking your device is not necessarily a developer question. We have let past questions stand in regards to rooting and unlocking.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs due to a specific state setting in some HTC devices that results in the phone not being able to make a desktop passthrough connection. This state condition can be mitigated by following the steps below.

Use the following workaround.

1. If connected, unplug the phone device from the computer.

On the phone device:

1. Press the Windows button.
2. Press the right arrow button (on the top right of the screen) or swipe from right to left to expose the application list.
3. Scroll to and select  “Settings”.
4. Scroll to and select “Cellular”.
5. Select “Change Network Profile" and then wait for this selection change to complete.
6. Press the Back or Windows key to exit the “Settings” menu.

After completing the above steps, follow through with the registration process:

1. Connect the Sprint Arrive to the development PC with the USB cable included with the phone device.
2. Launch the Windows Phone Developer Registration Tool  (Zune software must be running).
3. The window titled "Windows Phone Developer Registration" appears which establishes a connection to the phone device and the following status message:  "Status: Phone ready. Please enter your Windows Live ID and password and click Register to begin".
4. Enter the App Hub registered Windows Live ID and password, and then press the "Register" button.

If that doesn't work for you, then the error message is because of a certificate problem. [This link](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9767934) will download a Microsoft Fix-It app that will automatically repair the security certificates for Zune.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to have the phone turned on and see the start screen or app list

What I do is:

1. Open Zune
2. "Turn on my phone" - just getting to the start menu
3. Connect phone with the USB cable
4. Wait until Zune shows my Phone (instead of Device) in the menu

Comment: point number 4 mean sync right? yeahh i've also done with it.

Comment: Yes. If you see your phone in Zune then everything should be working fine. If this isn't helping then I have no clue :(

Comment: btw thank you for commenting in this post, i really appreciate your answer. i know that this is frustating one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you did this, but when did you sign up for a developer account? You need a developer account to unlock your phone for dev.  Once you can login to http://create.msdn.com you can then dev-unlock your phone.

Comment: Well now the proble is I have registered my self as a developer on wp dev over a week ago, but I still have any issue regarding unlock my htc radar, i have launched Zune and also no pin lock on my phone but the Windows phone dev registration can't register me to unlock my phone, it said unable to connect to phone. Any idea?

Comment: Is Zune seeing the phone? Aka does it show up at the top of the page?

Comment: Yes zune recognize my phone "HTC Radar",

Comment: Send me a private email and let me get someone to help you.  jhealy et Microsoft dit com

Comment: Well, I have sent you a private mail, thanks.